Windowing Function To Keep Track Of "Latest Seen" Row
I have the following test data:



Id
Special




1
0


2
0


3
1


4
0


5
0


6
0


7
1


8
0


9
0



And I want to compute this:



Id
Special
LastSeenSpecial




1
0
NULL


2
0
NULL


3
1
3


4
0
3


5
0
3


6
0
3


7
1
7


8
0
7


9
0
7



from it.
I have thought about a query snippet that does something like MIN(Id) OVER (PARTITION BY Special ORDER BY Id), but the partitioning comes out wrong and the default value for rows with Id 1 and 2 come out as 1, instead of the required NULL. How can I achieve this? I figure I need to use windowing in some way, but there's no need to use ROW_NUMBER() since Id is already effectively the row number.
What do?

How big (# of rows magnitude) will your expected data be and will you always be processing all of the data? What works well when selecting the entire table containing a dozen rows may have severe performance issues when scaled up to a million rows when you only need the latest thousand.

One way is to use a windowed MAX with conditional aggregation Fiddle
SELECT Id, 
       Special, 
       MAX(CASE WHEN Special = 1 THEN Id END) OVER (ORDER BY Id ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING)
FROM YourTable 
ORDER BY Id

You could also use
 LAST_VALUE (CASE WHEN Special = 1 THEN Id END) IGNORE NULLS OVER (ORDER BY Id ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING )

If you are on a version of SQL Server supporting IGNORE NULLS here.

This is my preferred solution, but correlated subqueries will work on versions of SQL Server that do not support OVER (PARTITION BY...ORDER BY...)

You can also use a subquery:
select m1.id, 
       m1.special,
      (select max(id) 
       from MyTbl m2 
       where m2.Special=1 
         and m2.id<=m1.id) as LastSeenSpecial
from MyTbl m1

